# Dynatree slow when dynamically loaded with 100+ nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynatree

How do I speed it up?

I get the results from JSON web service (lightning fast). Adding nodes to the tree using

something like

```
parentNode.addChild({
        key: key,
        title: value,
        addClass: cssClass
    });
```

Unfortunately, a tree with 100+ elements takes 1.5 minutes to load.
I am disappointed...is it not made to be used with that many nodes? Anything I can do at this point aside from switching to another component?

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding an array of elements?

Comment: that's what I am doing now:) seems faster than using node.AddChild(child)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This benchmark shows that it is loads pretty fast:
http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/test-bench.html
(Theres always room for improvement though...)

Your problem might be, that you load and add the nodes seperately?
In this case the tree is also *rendered* 100+ times, and that *is* slow indeed.

Have a look at the sample, to see how load a batch of nodes with one call:
http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-lazy.html

Comment: yes indeed. i found that out yesterday. it would help to say that in the notes for dynatree:) I was adding each node separately. The faster method would be to pass an array of children (initialized according to format) to a node....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an example of lazy loading the tree. Might try that out: http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/samples.html

Comment: as I said the delay is not on the database side or web service side, it's populating the tree that's slow.....
i am working on it now and will report with the results, hopefully others will benefit.